# Can integers be strongly typed to specific ranges?

Tags: rust, numbers, strong-typing

Can Rust strongly type integers to defined ranges?

For example, I'd like to define a type to represent months, which can be [1 .. 12], inclusive. Range checking would panic if this variable goes beyond this range.

Comment: Not in the core, no. You're going to need to build an `enum` or `struct` or two on top of the basic types. You might also want to consider how you would "throw exceptions" in a language that doesn't have them as a core feature (some crates emulate them with macros), also ;-)

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Same way the rest of Rust does on overflow/underflow. It panics in debug mode, and is not checked in production.

Comment: Panicking by default and without an alternative is probably a bit too strict, in my own opinion. Of course, I don't know your use case, but surely there's more than one occasion where returning a `Result` as opposed to panicking would be preferable (and would therefore be easy to implement with a `TryFrom` implementation)

Comment: The [ux crate](https://crates.io/crates/ux) might be of interest. It only has sizes limited to powers of 2, but you get types like `u3` and `i42`.

Comment: If you can use unstable features, you can implement your own ranged integer type using const generics. The ergonomics won't be as nice as native support for ranged types, but you should get some of the benefits you are looking for. (In many cases a custom type for a specific use case is probably your best option.)

Comment: If `rust` can have [dependent type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), that'll be rad.